# Implement sign with digital certificate on spring based web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-applications, digital-signature

I have spring mvc based web application. One of the use  cases requires a customer to digitally sign the information that he provides in a form . This signature then gets embedded into a PDF that will be generated on confirmation. How can I implement this in secure manner.

Currently I request the customer to download the PDF and sign it  it offline and then upload it again as I do not want them to upload their private keys to the server

Could you please recommend a better approach for the same

Comment: how about using services like DocuSign ? https://www.docusign.in/

Comment: I mean using a certificate (issued to by certified authorities )

Answer (score 0):

The user could provide his private key in the form but it never gets send to the Server. Instead all the other fields of the form are sent to the server, the server then sends back the SHA hash of the generated PDF. Now this hash can be signed locally and the resulting signature can be sent back again to the server and be attached to the PDF.

However most users would never provide their private key in any online form and additionally it is not that easy to create a digital signature inside the form.

So instead you can go for a partial approach where the user just has to sign the SHA hash of the PDF and paste its signature on the next page of the form. So now download / upload is required. I would still make the download of the PDF optional so the user can check if the hash is valid.